# Prove that $xx^T\leq \|x\|^2 I$?

Tags: normed-spaces

For a vector of real number $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, is that true that:
$$xx^T \leq ||x||^2 I, $$
where $I \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ is the identity matrix. For two matrices $A$ and $B$ we say  $A \leq B \ $ if  $\ B-A$ is a semi-positive definite matrix. If that is true what is nice way to prove that.

Thanks

Comment: You can also think about inner products as well. What happens if you do $y^T (xx^T) y$?

Comment: Hint: This is equivalent to $$(x\cdot y)^2\leq \|x\|^2\|y\|^2$$ for all vectors $y.$

Comment: Thanks, I can solve it based on your suggestion Thomas.